# VBA To Perform Calculation

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013, worksheet-function

I am trying to use VBA to add a calculation to the used range of multiple worksheets.  Problem is, I keep getting this error

> 'Type Mismatch'

on the line reading `ws.Cells(countie, 12).FormulaR1C1 =...`

Here is my syntax - what will fix this so this syntax will execute?

```
Function JunctionTest()
Dim ws As Worksheet, countie As Long
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  With ws
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
    LastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*",After:=.Range("A1"),LookAt:=xlPart, _
                  LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows,SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                  MatchCase:=False).Row
  Else
    LastRow = 1
  End If
  For countie = 1 To LastRow
        ws.Cells(countie, 12).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC7+RC8" / "=VLookup(A2, Totals!B2:R100, 3, False)"
Next countie
End Function
```

EDIT --

[Download Sample Workbook - Garbagedata.xlsx](http://www.filedropper.com/garbage)

Comment: it looks like youre trying to incorrectly use worksheet formalus - i could be wrong though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "=RC7+RC8" / "=VLookup(A2, Totals!B2:R100, 3, False)"

Remove the equal sign from `"=VLookup(`.

You can not mix `R1C1` notation with `A1` notation: `RC7+RC8` & `A2` don't mix

Instead of killing yourself trying to build a FormulaR1C1 in the VBA, get the formula working correctly on the worksheet and then print the working formula to the Immediate Window

[image]

### UPDATE

```
ws.Cells(countie, 12).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC7+RC8/VLOOKUP(RC1, Totals!R2C2:R100C18, 3, FALSE)"
```

---

```
Sub JunctionTest()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            lastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            .Range("L2:L" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC7+RC8/VLOOKUP(RC1, Totals!R2C2:R100C18, 3, FALSE)"
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I get a compile error.  Syntax Error.  Thank you for the valuable insight on getting formula to work correctly in the worksheet before attempting to put it together in VBA!

Comment: I moved the quote from before Totals to after the closing paren and it compiles, and runs, but the worksheet shows #Name? for everything.

Comment: Yes, if it matters that is the first sheet in the workbook

Comment: just added file of garbage data

Comment: @StarsFlyFreeFromCozyNights I updated my answer.   My formula was a little off.